# Is there an intuitive see why $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{x/n}-1}{x/n} = 1$

Tags: limits, exponential-function

I'm almost certain the following is true:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{x/n}-1}{x/n} = 1$$

At first blush, it would seem (to me at least) that this would approach infinity.  However, upon further investigation however, it doesn't...it's 1.  Is there a some intuitive way to think about this?

Comment: You mean that the limit $x/n$? This doesn't even make sense as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: The value of the limit should not depend on $n$.

Comment: the limit is zero

Comment: You might think of $e^{\frac{x}n}-1=\frac{x}n+o\left(\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)$. Use the power series of $exp$ and you get $e^y=1+y+o(y^2)$. If $y$ goes to $0$ your exponential function looks more and more like $1+y$, since $o(y^2)$ vanishes faster than $y$. Therefore you get $e^{\frac{x}n}-1=1+\frac{x}n+o\left(\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)-1=\frac{x}n+o\left(\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)$.

Comment: Perhaps the usage of 'limit' is not correct here - but as n gets arbitrarily big  e^(x/n)-1 becomes closer and closer to the function f(x) = x/n.  Hope that is clear.  Perhaps 'convergence' is a better term to use here than 'limit'?

Comment: @CShreve Please check your equation carefully. Make sure that it makes sense in some way. Then make an edit.

Comment: This is just the fact that the derivative of $e^t$ at $t=0$ is $1.$

Answer (score 1):

The limit in your post is zero, since $e^{x/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.
However, you are probably thinking of something like
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{x/n}-1}{x/n} = 1,$$
which can be viewed roughly as "$e^{x/n} - 1 \approx x/n$" as $n \to \infty$.

Indeed, by replacing $y=x/n$ and taking $y \to 0$, the above is the same as
$$\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{e^y-1}{y} = 1.$$
This can be verified by writing out the definition of the derivative of $f(y)=e^y$ at zero: $f'(y) = 1$.

Alternatively, this can be verified by looking at the Taylor series $e^y = 1 + y + O(y^2)$ as $y \to 0$, as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is referring to the original question:

> I'm almost certain the following is true:
>
> $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(e^{\frac x n} - 1
>  \right) = {\frac x n}$
>
> At first blush, it would seem (to me at least) that this limit would
>   be 0.  However, upon further investigation however, it isn't...rather
>   it's x/n.  Is there a some intuitive way to think about this?

It is true that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^n=e^x \qquad \color{blue}\checkmark$$

It seems that you then made some transformations which are not valid. You take the n-th root on both sides. But since $n \to \infty$ on the LHS you cannot just put it on the the RHS like

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}1+\frac{x}{n}=e^{x/n} \qquad \color{red}X$$

Consequently subtracting 1 on both sides does not make it even better.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\lim_{\Delta x\to0} \frac{e^{\Delta x} - e^0}{\Delta x - 0} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta e^x}{\Delta x} = \frac{d e^x}{dx} = e^x = e^x = 1 \text{ if } x=0.
$$